# How to change the text of this jquery object

Tags: jquery

How do I change the text of the jQuery object. I'm just trying to become more familiar here. This does not work:

```
$(responseFieldHTML).html('hi')
```

The jquery returns this jQuery object:

```
$(responseFieldHTML)
w.fn.init [div.server_response]
```

This does work:

```
$('.server_response').html('hi')
w.fn.init [div.server_response, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

What am I not understanding?

FYI the `responseFieldHTML` is just this:

```
  var responseFieldHTML = `
    <div class='server_response'>
    </div?
  `
```

which gets painted on the DOM earlier.

Comment: Might help if your HTML was valid.

Comment: Also, how are you determining that it does not work? I only ask as it works fine for me in my console (after fixing the HTML), eg `console.log($('<div class="server_response"></div>').html('hi')[0])`

Comment: @randal4 nothing wrong with wrapping html in `$()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `responseFieldHTML` is an ajax response you need to store it as an object and then insert that object or parse the object back to html string after you modify it

```js
  var responseFieldHTML = `
    <div class='server_response'>
    </div>
  `
  // create jQuery object from html string and modify it
  var $response = $(responseFieldHTML).html('Hi !!').css('color','red');
  // insert as object
  $('body').append($response);
  // can still modify it after inserted
  $response.addClass('new-class')

  // or parse modified html to string
  console.log($response[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```